# how to compare two audio files in iphone?

Tags: ios

I need to generate fingerprint of audio file (audio data) and

compare recorded audio file with locally saved audio file to know both are same song or not ?

Comment: This is *a lot* more work than your simple question is making it out to be. I wouldn't expect a full, complete answer from anyone - it's not like `strcmp`.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your question the first time you stated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as theory is concerned you need to study:

1. Fast Fourier Transform
2. MFCC (Mel Frequency cepstrum coefficient)
3. DTW - Dynamic Time Warping / MSE - Mean Square Error

For implementing this step by step read this article for nokia mobile development, you can get good understanding of the flow and theory:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Sound_pattern_matching_using_Fast_Fourier_Transform_in_Windows_Phone

And for sample project you can find exactly the thing you are looking for:
https://github.com/hfink/matchbox